# Anchor Tag Download (Not Working in IE) (href from external link) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Thanks in advance,

```
<a class="external" href="http://externalsite.com/download/example.ex5" download>Download file external</a>
```

If the file is in same server, it will download in IE.

If the file is not in the same server, it will not downloaded in IE.

In my case the file is from an external server.

Comment: Getting page not found on that url

Comment: Thanks, It is the example url Toretto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download property is supported in Firefox, Opera and Chrome.

Note: The download property is not supported in Internet Explorer, Safari or Opera 12 and earlier versions.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_download.asp

I hate to quote w3schools, I know.

Comment: yes i know these details CaitLAN but it is working if the file in same server <a href="images/example.ex5" download>Download file</a>

Comment: The issue is particularly attributed to Internet Explorer's implementation of HTML5.

Comment: Basically, you're saying "well it does work when I host the file" which may be true, but it doesn't change the fact that Internet Explorer doesn't appropriately implement this HTML5 functionality, which is the problem.

Comment: Even though  <a href="images/example.ex5">Download file</a>In IE it will work if the download attribute is not present

Comment: <a href="images/example.ex5">Download file</a> is still a local path. If you are trying to download from a path that isn't local, the best you can get out of Internet Explorer (it appears) is opening the hypertext reference in a new window. Then the user could initiate a download.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need this to work in IE? In Firefox, Opera, and Chrome it works fine.

Comment: Thanks CaitLAN,yes my client raise the issue it will not work in IE that's why i wanna solution, if possible

Comment: Well I'm sorry to tell you the bad news, but you can't control the fact that IE doesn't fully support HTML5 features. That's what you have to tell you clients. Until IE addresses this (you could open a support ticket with microsoft), you will be unable to deliver this particular HTML5 feature to your clients using IE.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this response, please mark the question as answered. Sorry I couldn't be any more helpful.